# Why is weak questions not allowed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question: [How do we recognize hardware used in accelerator physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28633/how-do-we-recognize-hardware-used-in-accelerator-physics)
has been closed. It is true, that no answer in closed form can be given. -but I still feel that it is a interesting question, and I was really looking forward to see some answers. -so sad...

Answer (score 4):

This is a make-a-list question and is ill-suited to the question and answer format of Stack Exchange sites.

Perhaps I should have chosen "Not constructive" as the close reason:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

I apologize for the confusion.

This [is a Stack Exchange wide policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) and is encoded in the FAQ [section entitled "What kind of questions should I not ask here?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask):

> avoid asking subjective questions where [...] every answer is equally valid

Comment: I understand the reason for closing the question, but I do not understand why it is a valid reason. I think that many would find it interesting to have a list of names and links collected in one place. Off cause this could be broken down in a million questions(one for each thing), but it would not benefit anyone.

Comment: It took about two and half years on Stack Overflow to show just how badly that works, but the short version is that mindless bikeshedding questions push out the real Q&A.

Comment: I have seen some questions before, where the answer is the combination of all the 'answer posts'. Have found one example(but in meta). http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/what-are-your-favourite-tikz-pgf-answers/

Comment: I do not know what "bikeshedding" means here.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality ... in this case I mean characterized by being answerable by anyone [with access to google images](http://www.google.com/search?q=beam+current+monitor&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=3Em5T96cK-issQK9yPWKDA&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CHcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1067&bih=555).

Comment: You successfully found pictures "beam current monitor"'s, but my question is about the reverse look up. Given a picture(or real life experience), how will I know what this thing is!?

Comment: Can you answer this question? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28676/what-is-this-thing-seen-on-the-picture

Comment: *"but my question is about the reverse look up"* Your own answers make it clear that the question is *"lets make a list with pictures"*, nor can you reasonably hope to assembly a comprehensive list and if you did it wouldn't be useful because there is no way to search it.

Comment: Yes  "lets make a list with pictures" is **exactly** what I would like, because it is interesting, and fun. The search would be done by looking and scrolling down - the human brain is amazing.

Comment: @Hans-Peter, please understand that we're not saying that is necessarily a bad question, just that it is not appropriate for a Stack Exchange site. We are not trying to be all things to all people here; we are trying to fill a niche, which is to create a resource of direct answers to practical, focused questions, and do it better than anyone else. There are lots of ways of presenting useful information which do not fit into that goal, and there are a number of other physics Q&A or reference sites around the web where those sorts of things would be appropriate.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen, and the only answer to the question linked above is an "I guess" with a google picture for a possible reference. Not great answers in my opinion. If klystrons were easily made for that power at that size it would be awesome.